# iPad language glitch

Tags: ipad

How do I switch to Australian Store on my iPad, it appears to have gone to the French store and is telling me I can't update unless I switch to Australian store, I don't know what to do as I have checked in settings etc.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings -> iTunes & App Store -> [your Apple ID] -> View Apple ID`.

Change the `Country/Region` (below `Payment Information`).

Select your region, agree to terms, and you're done.